# When using a connection-pool should I get the connection each query or once each batch?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have been unable to find an exact answer to this question.  I'm using C3P0's `ComboPooledDataSource`.  Which of these methodologies is better practice:

```
dataSource = connectionClass.getDataSource();
conn = dataSource.getConnection;
executeQuery(query1, conn);
executeQuery(query2, conn);
...
executeQuery(finalQuery, conn);
conn.close();
```

OR

```
executeQuery(query1);
executeQuery(query2);
...
executeQuery(finalQuery);
```

where `executeQuery`:

```
conn = dataSource.getConnection;
st = conn.createStatement();
rs = executeQuery(query);
conn.closed();
```

In short, I have to do a decent amount of queries every so often.  Is it better to go with the first design, which gets the connection once for each batch and passes it as an argument.  Or is it better to go with the second approach and just get a connection each time I call my executeQuery method.  If I was using `DriverManager` I would obviously choose the first (only get the connection once), but when using the C3P0 package I am not sure if doing that is the right way to go or not.  Or does it not matter with such a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a connection pool, the difference is neglectible, because even if you use the second approach, bringing back a pooled connection takes little time. Still, using the first approach is the better way to go, because

- It avoids the additional (little) overhead of getting a connection from the pool.
- If you later need to introduce transactions (do all of your changes or, in case of an error, conveniently and securely roll back your changes), then the first approach is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments/suggestions

- If you application is single threaded (*unless you mention*), it does not matter. It even does not matter whether you use connection pool or not. Just use a single connection and pass the same to function where you need it.
- Connection pools are useful when the use case involves **multiple database connections simultaneously**.
- Since your application is a batch and single threaded, it does not warrant use of connection pool.
- Regarding your application, both the approaches are equivalent. When you call connection.close() on pooled datasource connection, its not actually closed but returned to pool.

Comment: I switched to using a connection pool because my application has to remain up and running for months on end and the pool handles disconnects/reconnects.  Would it be better to just handle these on my own and use the DriverManager?

Comment: Well, handling disconnects/reconnects are one of the many thing pool offers. Your use case is very simple and as far as I understood, just a single connection would be enough. What I would recommend, open a connection before you need and do not close it unless you are finished.